# pip install -d not creating wheel for cffi

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, python-cffi

I'm trying to create "offline package" for python code.

I'm running
`pip install -d <dest dir> -r requirements.txt`
The thing is that `cffi==1.6.0` (inside requirements.txt) doesn't get built into a wheel.

Is there a way I can make it? (I trying to avoid the dependency in gcc in the target machine)

Comment: What's the output when you run the `pip` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`install -d` just downloads the packages; it doesn't build them.  To force everything to be built into wheels, use the [`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/) command instead:

```
pip wheel -w <dir> -r requirements.txt
```